# Eclipse RDT (PTP) Command not found "rm"

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I am using RSE to connect to a Linux RDT server. I connect through SOCKS (SSH tunneling from another machine) but that's not the issue, because I have the same problem when I connect directly (when I am in the same LAN).

The settings are pretty straightforward, and I can connect to the remote project and save files.

However, when I try to build I have:

`Error: Program "rm" not found in PATH`

Needless to say, the environment variable PATH is defined and yes, it points to `/bin` among others.

Anyone can guess what's the problem here?

After that, I have a `can not clean programmatically: build workspace path is not specified` message.

Comment: Rm can be installed as a part of coreutils but it is often a built-in shell command. Please look if you have an executable named rm in your `$PATH`. You can also try this command : `which rm`.

Comment: Hi, user2284570. As I imply, `rm` is in fact installed under `/bin` in the remote machine, the one that is supposed to compile the project. It is important to note that Eclipse is asking a remote compilation to a full featured Linux machine running a RDT-server, from a Windows machine. The fact that the 'RDT client' is Windows should not affect (in fact, from Linux to Linux there are similar results)

Comment: Try to get the executable installed on both.

Comment: How are you checking the value of PATH?

Comment: @Jake Yes, both the Eclipse environment PATH and the remote machine's RSE user have the correct directory in their PATH. Instead of using RDT, now I am using SMB and just compiling it invoking `make` in a ssh session. RDT is too slow and buggy imho. Pity.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simple use absolute pathname? /bin/rm

also ' ' (spaces) in PATH could give you problems.